# TypeError when extracting pincode from resume

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have to extract data from resumes. And when I try to extract pincode from resume the below error occurred and I can't rectify it.

I am passing a file object and read through `open()` and then saved it to the variable called `_datas_`. I am using python 3.6.

Below is the code I used:

```
import re 

def pincode_fetch(pincode):
    pincode = re.search(r"^[1-9]\d{5}$", pincode)
    return pincode

print(pincode_fetch(datas))
```

The expected output is like this: `"686533"`.
But I got an error like this:

```
--> 182     return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
    183 
    184 def sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: what was the pincode that you passed?

Comment: 'datas' is the resume i passed as .txt file @PeterWood

Comment: 'pincode' is the parameter passed in pincode_fetch() @Jeril

Comment: re.search doesn't accept file object, you should pass a string object instead as the error informs.

Comment: can you share the sample pincode which is causing this issue

Comment: datas1="Carnival technopark trivandrum 686533"

import re
def pincode_fetch(pincode):
    pincode=re.search(r"^[1-9]\d{5}$",pincode)
    return pincode

print(pincode_fetch(datas1))

Comment: @JinuJoseph edit the question. With the code given in your comment I get the result: `None`. This is because you are matching the beginning of a line with `^`, so there is no match to `Carnival`. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Sir I showed a part of the resume where i want the picode tobe fetched. i cannot share the whole resume. When i am using a resume file i got the error below _TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object_ . @PeterWood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 import re 
 pincodesearch = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d\d\d)') 
 mo = pincodesearch.search('Carnival technopark trivandrum 686533') 
 print(mo.groups())[0]
```

Comment: this is only for 5 digit just add one more \d in  like re.compile(r'(\d\d\d\d\d\d)')

Comment: It worked  but when using it on resume  it takes the first 5 numbers of the Contact number given @Yash shukla

Comment: pincodesearch = re.compile(r'(\d\d\d\d\d\d)') just add one more \d ,bymistake i added only 5(\d) .sorry

Comment: I tried but Not working on a resume as it takes the first 6 numbers of contact number @Yash Shukla

Comment: It's for pin code not for a contact number if you want contact number you will have to add 10(\d) for separately for the contact number.

Comment: Yes I want to extract the 6 Digit pin code but when using the code  shared by you the output was the first 6 digit of mobile number. @Yash Shukla

Answer (score 1):

You can use find all, its working

```
import re 
def pincode_fetch(pincode):
   pincode = re.findall(r"^[1-9]\d{5}$",pincode)
   return Pincode


 print (pincode_fetch('221507'))


Ans -[221507]
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But When using  pincode_fetch("Carnival technopark trivandrum 686533")  the output is _none_ .

Comment: Welcome, Jinu !!